# How to get object in view according to x , y ( touchesMoved )

Tags: ios, xcode, touchesmoved, uievent

i would like to get the `UIImageView` ( or whatever I have ) in the view according to the xPos and yPos using this method :

```
- (void) touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  CGPoint tappedPt = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:viewIndex];
  int     xPos = tappedPt.x;
  int     yPos = tappedPt.y;

  NSLog(@"xPos %i yPos %i ", xPos, yPos);


  // do something with xPos and yPos like add them to an array
}
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Did you mean to move some view according to these touch points?

Comment: nop i will like to know, that everytime i move the the finger, ( so i get the x and y ) if there is a uiimageview or not and if there is a uiimageview i get it and resize it.

Answer (score 0):

Should not be much difficult to check whether a point lies in some rect or not, provided you know the frame of UIImageView object.

But have you tried creating a subclass of UIView, add an image to it. And that class object on your rather than adding a UIImageView object over it, and implementing the touches methods in this UIView's  subclass rather than in you UIViewController class?

Comment: but i know that there is a easiest way to do it, but cannot find the method, something which sounds like " object exist at this frame "
thanks for reply

Comment: Don't forget to let others know when you recall that. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything that walks through the child hierarchy.  You can cut out a little of the work using the UIView method :-

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

where event can be nil, but you'll still have to do that test to each child, and potentially it's descendents.

Answer (score -1):

you can get all subviews of the main view. and then determine whether the touch point in the subviews.

```
for(UIView *aView in [self subviews])
{
    if(CGRectContainsPoint(aView.frame, tappedPt))
    {
        return aView;
    }
}
```

but it has a problem . if many subviews are overlapping , you can only get a view . you can modify the code to get a view array.

Comment: you really should do it like this!!! There is no way, that is easier. `CGRectContainsPoint` is already what you're looking for. For checking if it is a UIImageView you simply insert `if([aview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class])`